# Div positioning help css

Tags: css, html

Take a look at this image...

[image: Image A]

All of the boxes are divs. How can I position them like that? Here's what I got so far...

```
#container{
    position:relative;
    padding:25px;
}

#div1 {
    float:left;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    padding:25px;
}

#div2 {
    clear:both;
    margin-left: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    padding:25px;
}

#div3 {
    float:right;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    width: 300px;
    padding:25px;
}
```

With the code above..div1 and div2 is position properly somehow. But div3 is on the lower part of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would `float:right` div3 and have it first in your HTML and then just have div1 and div2 not floated.

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/eErVT/

Comment: I think he has to specify a width for the container as well in that case.

Comment: It didn't worked..div3 moved up but they are not still leveled

Comment: @samn, not required. the container should be 100% wide as its parent.

Answer (score 0):

...or you could wrap div1 and div2 in its own wrap, and float that.

Comment: Well, yes, there usually is, and undoubtedly some suggestions will follow below :-) but the question then is how you want your site to work, and how the structure should act.  I would be careful with absolute positioning, others are happy with it. I work with responsive design, and are therefore careful about positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your left divs in a single column. So your markup would look something like this:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="main">
    <div id="div1">div1</div>
    <div id="div2">div2</div>
  </div>
  <div id="div3">div3</div>
</div>
```

Then your css would look like this:

```
#container{
    position:relative;
    padding:25px;
}
#main {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
}
#div1 {
    padding:25px;
}
#div2 {
    padding:25px;
}
#div3 {
    float:right;
    width: 100px;
    padding:25px;
}
```

Here's an example fiddled: http://jsfiddle.net/neilheinrich/ez2rQ/

Answer (score 0):

An alternate that doesn't require adding extra divs is to use absolute positioning on `div3`, along with extra padding on `container` to create space for `div3`.

See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/y2fJS/

CSS:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
#container{
    position:relative;
    border-color: green;
    padding: 50px 200px 50px 50px; /* right padding (150) should include div3 width+padding+margin */
}

#div1 {
    padding:25px;
}

#div2 {
    padding:25px;
}

#div3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    padding:25px;
}
```

EDIT: One problem I forgot to mention is that the absolutely positioned `div3` will no longer contribute to the height of the outer div.  So, if you have a long `div3` this may not work without some additional trickery.

Comment: Do your div1 and div2 have dynamic content as well?  You can always flip the trick around if div3 is dynamic, but div1 & div2 are of a fixed height.  Alternatively, if you know the height of div3, you can add a `min-height: <div3 height>;` to `#container`.

Answer (score -1):

Here this looks like your picture, but i would suggest looking at sites like http://www.cssplay.co.uk/ for site design.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Div Positioning</title>
        <style type='text/css'>

            #div1
            {
                position: absolute;
                top: 25px;
                left: 25px;
                height: 200px;
                width: 200px;
                border: 1px solid red;
            }

            #div2
            {
                position: absolute;
                top: 250px;
                left: 25px;
                height: 200px;
                width: 200px;
                border: 1px solid red;
            }

            #div3
            {
                position: absolute;
                top: 25px;
                left: 250px;
                height: 425px;
                width: 300px;
                border: 1px solid red;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='div1'></div>
        <div id='div2'></div>
        <div id='div3'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: wheres the `container` using absolute everywhere is overkill and will not be flexible for future changes.

Comment: @MoinZaman I only created what jovhenni19 asked for.  The container itself is the body adding another container serves no purpose.   I made a point of directing jovhenni19 to look at sites like cssplay to address the lack design consideration in the question.   I didn't suppose to know what jovhenni19 was hoping to get out of the question asked and offered an answer that matched the question.