# Two fixed iframe s (or div s) on the side

Tags: html, css, iframe

I can not see `side2.html` below the `side1.html`

`page.html`  should scroll, `side1.html` and `side2.html` should be always visible, side1 above side2.

page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        <!--
        body.container {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
        .maintext {
            float: right;
            width: calc(100% - 210px);
        }
        iframe.side1 {
            position: fixed;
            float: left;
            height: 600px;
            width: 200px;
        }
        iframe.side2 {
            position: fixed;
            float: left;
            top: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            width: 200px;
        }
        -->
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<a name="topw" id="toppage"></a>

<div class="container">
    <div class="maintext">
        <a name="dic"></a><h3>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dict</h3><br/>
    </div>
    <iframe class="side1" src="side1.html" frameborder="0" />
    <iframe class="side2" src="side2.html" frameborder="0" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

side1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a class="menu" target="_parent" href="page.html#dic" title="title"       > title </a>

</body>

</html>
```

side2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.ubuntu.com" title="org">.org</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Or could I solve the problem just with `div`, without `iframe`. Something like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899632/div-positioning-help-css). But I can not make it work: side1 above side2

Comment: Use `left: 0;` instead `float: left;` and `right: 0;` instead  `float: right;`. Because fixed elements can't be floated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **you should close your iframes** with `</iframe>`, because they aren't empty elements *(to deal with browsers that do not support `<iframe>`, you could add a text between the opening and the closing tag of the iframe)*: https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/iframe
- **use `top` and `left`** to position absolute when your element is `position: fixed`

I've modified your code (see comments):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>page</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        body.container {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .maintext {
            float: right;
            width: calc(100% - 210px);
        }
        iframe.side1 {
            position: fixed;
            left: 0; /* use absolute positions when position fixed, not float */
            top: 0;
            height: 300px; /* 300px is enough, else it is behind your second iframe*/
            width: 200px;
        }
        iframe.side2 {
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
            top: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            width: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<a name="topw" id="toppage"></a>

<div class="container">
    <div class="maintext">
        <a name="dic"></a><h3>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dict</h3><br/>
    </div>

    <!-- always add a closing tag to your iframes -->
    <iframe class="side1" src="side1.html" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
    <iframe class="side2" src="side2.html" frameborder="0" ></iframe>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope that solve your problem...

Comment: I am closing iframe with `/>`

Comment: Yes you close your iframes with that, but `<el></el>` and `<el/>` are not the same tags, the first one is an element which can has any content and the second one is empty and can't have content or child elements. if you want to write valid html, you should use `<iframe></iframe>`

Answer (score 1):

Position fixed needs positioned elements **top/right/down/left** to reference it's offset. `float` will not work on fixed elements.

I have also change the height and offset of the elements so they will fill the users screen no matter what size it is.

Also as @Sim pointed out iframes are now self closing and should have a proper closing tag.

```css
body.container {
  width:100%;
}
.maintext {
  min-height:1080px; /*to simulate content*/
  width:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding-left:200px;
  background:#ddd;
}
.side1,
.side2{
  position: fixed;
  left:0; 
  width:200px;
}
iframe.side1 {
  top:0; 
  height:70%;
}
iframe.side2 {
  top:70%; 
  height:30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="maintext">
    <a name="dic"></a><h3>Middle Div</h3><br/>
  </div>
  <iframe class="side1" src="side1.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  <iframe class="side2" src="side2.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: this solution gives me side1 and 2 on the left and right, I am interesting on the left only

Comment: @andrej then simply change the fixed position to left. I have made the changes above. note that as `side1` is 600px high, if the users monitor is less than 600px they wont see it. You could use % (e.g 70% `side1` and 30% `side2`)

Comment: @andrej If this was helpful in anyway then please upvote it so other can also benefit from the solution.